# Build MinGW with buildroot

Tags: x86, mingw, x86-64, mingw-w64, buildroot

I am trying to build MinGW on buildroot so that I can use it as a dependency for another program. Is there a possibility to build in several steps? Or how could I build MinGW so that I can use it as a dependency for my other program?

Glad about any help.

Comment: MinGW is old, you should consider MinGW-w64. Note that to build it you need a lot of other dependencies too. Have you considered using a prebuilt version? You can get standalone builds from https://winlibs.com/ that require no installation (just extract the archive).

Comment: Sure, I use the source of MinGW-w64. But my problem is, that I need it on Linux not on Windows. And not on a normal Distribution like Ubuntu or Debian. I need to use it with [BuildRoot](https://www.buildroot.org/).